# Python tkinter functions with multiply Tk()

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I'm very new. Haven't gotten to "Classes" yet. Just trying to understand functions before I move forward. Trying to make a basic login widget that when the register button is clicked, it destroys the root window, launches the register window, then once the submit button is clicked, it gets the entry info and for right now, just prints it. I have one file that works but only has one Tk() window. Once you add another like the register function, the code no longer works. I figure it must be the order of operation that I am not understanding the concept of so I wanted some help. I have even tried to put the variables, "username_var, password_var into the register function since they are originally outside of the function but that didn't work either. Also tried calling global variables inside the register function but no luck there either. I worked on this for two days, so please don't think I didn't try all I could on my own. If you know of any documentation that I could read to better understand this, please let me know. I couldn't find anything on this topic.

```
from tkinter import *

# The first widget/container, not resizable
root = Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)

# variables to store the usernames and passwords
username_var = StringVar()
password_var = StringVar()
password2_var = StringVar()


''' Submit logic, if submit button is clicked or enter is pressed and username does not exist in variable list user_name and both password entries match, save username and password in variable list. '''


def submit():
    print('Your username is ' + username_var.get())
    if password_var == password2_var:
        print('Your password is ' + password_var.get())
    else:
        print('Passwords do not match')


''' register button logic(if register button is clicked, destroy root window, load register window. Register window will have one username and two password labels and entries, entries have textvariables, rw = register window '''


def register_user():
    root.destroy()
    register_window = Tk()
    rw_user_label = Label(register_window, text='Username')
    rw_user_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    rw_pass_label = Label(register_window, text='Password')
    rw_pass_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    rw_pass_label = Label(register_window, text='Password')
    rw_pass_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
    rw_user_entry = Entry(register_window, textvariable=username_var)
    rw_user_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    rw_pass_entry = Entry(register_window, textvariable=password_var, show='*')
    rw_pass_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    rw_pass_entry2 = Entry(register_window, textvariable=password2_var, show='*')
    rw_pass_entry2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    submit_button = Button(register_window, text='Submit', command=submit)
    submit_button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='ew')


# username and password labels with grid locations
user_label = Label(root, text='Username')
user_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

pass_label = Label(root, text='Password')
pass_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

# username and password entries with grid locations
user_entry = Entry(root)
user_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

pass_entry = Entry(root, show='*')
pass_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

# Login and Register buttons with grid locations, both call functions
login_button = Button(root, text='Login')
login_button.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ew')

register_button = Button(root, text='Register', command=register_user)
register_button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='ew')


# creates an infinite loop for main root widget until destroy function is called or the widget is exited out of
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Two problems I see: creating multiple instances of `Tk()` results in non-working vars (among various other problems), use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.  And you must call `.get()` on Tkinter vars to retrieve their current value - you're doing that in some places, but you're also doing things like `password_var == password2_var` that are simply going to return False (you're not comparing the *contents* of the vars at all).

Comment: Recommend the debugging technique of testing every single step - that way you know what is working and the only problem area is the new step. This seems tedious as a beginner but in the long run becomes very efficient as you learn.

Comment: @jasonharper When I use Toplevel(), it generates a blank window on top of my register window. Is this intended?

Comment: @InhirCode, is there a resource you recommend for learning how to write test cases. I think I do this good enough along the way but not sure. You didn't see any in my code because I usually write a test case and if it passes then I delete it an move on.

Comment: well I personally don't use test cases - use of print and pass is enough to check most things from testing where things are going to and from, type and value checking and results. Keeping it really simple is also a good test of fundamental design. Python does have the unitest module that you can read about in the Python docs to see if it suits you better.

Answer (score 0):

In the `register` function the entry textvariables are used as initial values to be placed as default in this code. Any changes to the textvariables in the entry don't happen unless they have been declared global inside `register`.

```
def register():
   global username_var, password_var, password2_var
```

so you are on the right track in terms of thinking about scope - a global variable has to be specified as global if it is changed inside a function scope. Otherwise it is simply referenced.